# Getting always initial value of state after updating the state from the local storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, timer

I'm using `react-timer-hook` package in my next.js project to display a timer like you can see in the screenshot below:

[image: Timer Screenshot]

Now the issue is I want to persist this timer elapsed time into the local storage and whenever the page reloads manually then I need the Timer to start from that specific elapsed time that I'm trying to get from the local storage, but whenever I reload the page manually then Timer starts from the initial state's value. below are the codes:

Timer Component

```
function Timer({ seconds, minutes, hours }) {
    return (
        <Typography variant="h5" fontWeight={'bold'} component={'div'}>
            <span>{String(hours).padStart(2, '0')}</span>:
            <span>{String(minutes).padStart(2, '0')}</span>:
            <span>{String(seconds).padStart(2, '0')}</span>
        </Typography>
    );
}
```

I'm adding 3600 seconds into `expiryTimestamp` i.e., current date and time to get one hour of Timer.

```
let expiryTimestamp = new Date();
expiryTimestamp.setSeconds(expiryTimestamp.getSeconds() + 3600);
```

Aslo I'm using another state with same 3600 seconds initial value

```
const [elapsed, setElapsed] = useState(3600);
```

I'm using useEffect and decrementing the elapsed value on every second into local storage.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('elapsed', JSON.stringify(elapsed--));
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [elapsed]);
```

Now I'm getting the elapsed value from the local storage

```
useEffect(() => {
    const elapsed = localStorage.getItem('elapsed');
    if (elapsed) {
        setElapsed(JSON.parse(elapsed));
    }
}, []);
```

Again I'm using another variable to create current date and time + elapsed value

```
let currentTime = new Date();
currentTime.setSeconds(currentTime.getSeconds() + elapsed);
```

Finally I'm passing the `currentTime` in `useTimer` hook

```
const { seconds, minutes, hours } = useTimer({
    expiryTimestamp: currentTime,
    onExpire: handleForm,
});
```

Elapsed time is properly storing in the local storage, but still Timer starts from 3600 seconds.

Comment: Have you tried offsetTimestamp property in react-timer-hook. It defines the initial value for the timer. I think you can store both the current time and the time when the timer started, When page reloads, you can subtract currentTime from the time when timer started and set it as offsetTimestap in the timer. It will do the trick probably. Hope it helps.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqar, can you write an answer how can I achieve this???

Comment: Does your local storage value get set correctly? That will at least help you determine if it's an issue when setting or getting the value

Comment: elapsed time in seconds is storing in localstorage properly and I'm able to get the elapsed time but when I again use this time with current date and time then also timer starts from 1 hour. @Tom

Comment: I just want to persist the timer even when someone reload the page manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `expiryTimestamp` value of use timer as function to initiate its value.    Check the following component

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useTimer } from 'react-timer-hook';

export default function Timer() {
  const { seconds, minutes, hours } = useTimer({
    expiryTimestamp: () => {
      /** determine the expiry time stamp value all at once */
      const time = new Date(),
        elapsedTime = Number(window.localStorage.getItem('elapsed')) || 3600;
      time.setSeconds(time.getSeconds() + elapsedTime);
      return time;
    },
    onExpire: () => alert('expired')
  });

  /** update elapsed value in local storage */
  useEffect(() => {
    const elapsedSeconds = hours * 60 * 60 + minutes * 60 + seconds;
    window.localStorage.setItem('elapsed', elapsedSeconds);
  }, [seconds]);

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{String(hours).padStart(2, '0')}</span>:
      <span>{String(minutes).padStart(2, '0')}</span>:
      <span>{String(seconds).padStart(2, '0')}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you're using this component in next.js. You should use dynamic import with ssr disabled. otherwise you'll receive an error because SSR doesn't recognize the `window.localStorage` api. Check below

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import React from 'react';

const Timer = dynamic(() => import('./timer'), { ssr: false });

export default function Index = () => {
  return <Timer />;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your first useEffect hook is overwriting the value in local storage before you set your state from what's stored there.

Hooks fire in the order in which they are defined within a component, so your component is doing:

1. Set state to 3600
2. UseEffect where we set the local storage
3. UseEffect where we read local storage (whose value has just been overwritten to the default 3600) and set the state to that

You could try checking the local storage value and starting your interval in the same hook.

I'd first start by starting my default state with undefined

```
const [elapsed, setElapsed] = useState();
```

This lets me control the starting of the timer entirely within the useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    // make sure your first action is to get the elapsed time in local storage
    const storedElapsed = localStorage.getItem('elapsed');
    // work out if this is the initial load or not
    if (!elapsed) {
        // component state is not yet set, so use either local storage or the default
        const newElapsedState = JSON.parse(storedElapsed) || 3600;
        setElapsed(newElapsedState);
    } else {
        // we now know that state is set correctly, so can ignore local storage and start the timer
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            localStorage.setItem('elapsed', JSON.stringify(elapsed--));
        }, 1000);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, [elapsed]);
```

You will need to handle your first render being `undefined`, but after that your flow should be consistent as you have control over what is being set in what order.

You can control this by the order in which you define your useEffects, but I personally find this way a bit clearer as the logic is grouped together.

Comment: I tried this code and also handled the undefined but in first render I get current date and time and then I get the date and time with elapsed seconds, that's why timer expired instantly when I reload the page.

Comment: `let currentTime = new Date();
 if (typeof elapsed !== 'undefined' && elapsed !== null) {
  currentTime.setSeconds(currentTime.getSeconds() + parseInt(elapsed));
 }`

Comment: this is what I tried.

Comment: What are you using `currentTime` for?
Another option would be for you to just store the time the timer started in localStorage, and then compare it to the result of `new Date()` every time you set the state